# Twisted reactor.callLater() not caught in try except only on some machines

Tags: python, twisted, try-except

I'm using Twisted python and have code that basically looks like this:

```
class TimeoutException(Exception):
    pass


def timeout(msg):
    raise TimeoutExpection(msg)

def create_timeout(len, msg):
    return reactor.callLater(len, timeout, msg)
```

Elsewhere in the code...

```
try:
    timeout_call = create_timeout(10, "timeout")
    db_res = yield some_large_io_request()
except Exception as e:
    print e
    raise web.HTTPError(408) # cyclone error
else:
    if timeout_call.active():
        timeout_call.cancel()
```

This is running in a Docker container, however on some machines, the try except works, on others, I get an unhandled error for type TimeoutException, but I do still get a 408.  It is unclear to me how/why it is intermittent, any ideas?

Comment: These snippets are incomplete fragments.  What do you _expect_ to happen when this code runs, and why?  What do you observe happening instead (exactly - quote logs, preferably)?  And if you could make the snippets more complete, that would be great, too (for example, I'm *guessing* you're using `inlineCallbacks` but you haven't mentioned that in the question).

Comment: I expect the try except to catch exceptions and not get unhandled errors. and yes, I am using `inlineCallbacks` but that's not an important part of the code, you could delete that line and it's still the same behavior, that's just more realistic with it.

Comment: Catch what exception?

Comment: The one being raised in the timeout function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reactor.callLater` returns immediately.  The only thing it does is schedule a function to be called at some point in the future by the event loop.

Consider:

```
from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred

def foo():
    raise Exception("oh no")

def main(reactor):
    try:
        call = reactor.callLater(0, foo)
    except:
        print("Handling an exception!")
    else:
        print("Not handling an exception at all.")
        print("Got {}".format(call))
    print("Goodbye.")
    return Deferred()

react(main, [])
```

This program always produces this output:

```
Not handling an exception at all.
Got <DelayedCall 0x7fd082e28758 [-3.71932983398e-05s] called=0 cancelled=0 foo()>
Goodbye.
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/junk.py", line 18, in <module>
    react(main, [])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 936, in react
    _reactor.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1195, in run
    self.mainLoop()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1204, in mainLoop
    self.runUntilCurrent()
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 825, in runUntilCurrent
    call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
  File "/tmp/junk.py", line 5, in foo
    raise Exception("oh no")
exceptions.Exception: oh no
```

So, you cannot ever use try/except to handle exceptions raised by a function you schedule using `callLater`.